# Angular 4 - Cannot find name 'HttpClient'

Tags: angular

I'm trying to access a `JSON` feed but after making the changes from [the documentation](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6) I get the following error

> "Cannot find name 'HttpClient'"

I've looked over the tutorial a few times but I'm struggling to find why I get this error.

My component where I perform the Http request.

**rooms.parent.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 /.../
})

export class RoomParentComponent implements OnInit {
  results: string[];

  // Inject HttpClient into your component or service.
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Make the HTTP request:
    this.http.get(/.../).subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data;
    });
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RoomParentComponent } from './rooms.parent.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RoomParentComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

How do I resolve the above error and inject the HttpClient into the constructor?

Edit: My Angular version is 4.3.2

Comment: which version of angular ?

Comment: You should move your http stuff into a service and then inject the service instead of HttpClient into your component.

Comment: @Akkusativobjekt why not?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`HttpClient` got introduced in Angular `4.3.0` version. Also you have to make sure you have imported & injected `HttpClientModule` in your main `AppModule`'s `imports` metadata.

```
// Import HttpClientModule from @angular/common/http in AppModule
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';


//in place where you wanted to use `HttpClient`
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Comment: It didn't say use `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';` in the documentation but that has worked for me thank you!

Comment: The part saying "Before you can use the HttpClient, you need to install the HttpClientModule which provides it. This can be done in your application module, and is only necessary once." is particularly deceiving.

Comment: I needed to restart the application ng serve -o

Comment: Docs on this omit the import for HttpClient as stated by @JoshuaDuxbury https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: I don't know why, but VS Code does not give the usual suggestions for importing HttpClient / HttpClientModule. Copying your lines manually worked though! Thanks