# Cannot find name 'HttpClient', how to fix this error?

Tags: angular

When I try to launch project using `npm start` I get an error:

```
[at-loader] Checking finished with 1 errors
[at-loader] ./node_modules/@ngx-translate/http-loader/src/http-loader.d.ts:10:23 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'HttpClient'.
```

I tried to replace `http: HttpClient` on `http: Http`, also to reinstall `@ngx-translate`.

I have installed: `"@angular/common": "~4.1.2"`

How to fix it?

Comment: HttpClient is supported starting from Angular 4.3.0

Comment: What to use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tilde in  "@angular/http": "~4.1.2" means that you allow installing only the latest patches (e.g. 4.1.3, 4.1.4 etc).

Update your package.json to include the following dependencies (the hat sign in ^4.0.0 will take the latest minor release, which is 4.3):

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
```

Then delete your node_modules dir and run npm install.

Answer (score 1):

I face this 'HttpClient' problem today, but I am using **Ionic**. For those developers the solution is to use a previous version of http-loader.

> $ npm install @ngx-translate/core @ngx-translate/http-loader@**0.1.0** --save

See also: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/629

Answer (score -2):

Check if you have @angular/http in your node_modules.
If not, install it.

Comment: I have `   "@angular/http": "~4.1.2" in `package.json`

Comment: @Daniel try answer from that topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45375476/angular-2-cannot-find-name-httpclient

Comment: I does not work for me: `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`

Comment: @Daniel another hint from that topic:
You should move your http stuff into a service and then inject the service instead of HttpClient into your component.